# 18.04 - nVidia Drivers Issues

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, ubuntu-drivers

I am trying to get Ubuntu 18.04 LTS working on my laptop with Nvidia GPU but I have had no success.

What I have done:

I start with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. In order to log in, I edit the kernel to have "nomodeset" instead of "quiet splash." I then install the Nvidia 396 drivers and reboot. For whatever reason, every time I reboot, I get stuck at a screen that says "/dev/sda2: clean xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx files and xxxxxxx/xxxxxx blocks." Then nothing happens. I have found the way to get around this is to changed "nomodeset quiet splash" in the kernel to "nouveau.modeset=0" however, I do not want to have to do this every time I log in. If I try to add a "blacklist.conf" file with the option in there it does not seem to change the kernel at all.

Specs:

- MSI Stealth Pro Laptop
- i7-6700 Hq
- Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB
- 16 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

the 396 version is beta version delete completely that version and reinstall the stable version i gues it was 390 it may work

Answer (score 0):

nvidia 390 has issues with hybrid cards as well as multiple gpus but works as expected if you only have 1 gpu.

I have 1x GTX1080 and 1x GTX 960 and the 390 drivers leave me at a black screen unless I remove one of the cards. Currently I have downloaded and installed the latest beta drivers from nvidia, using both cards on Xubuntu 18.04 and nouveau blacklisted.